# jQuery fade image gradient to 0

Tags: jquery, gradient, fade

Is it possible using jQuery to fade an image from 100% at the top to 0% at the bottom.

The idea being to create a gradual fade of an image across its height.

Comment: [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1014-Creating-Transparent-Gradients-With-jQuery.htm) technique will do what you want, but using a transparent .png in the background is probably the best solution. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045319/creating-a-linear-transparent-gradient-to-a-div).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use transparent png in the background, then u can use the jQuery way that is provided [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1014-Creating-Transparent-Gradients-With-jQuery.htm)

I hope this will help!